# Order search results on Google by first time of appearance

Tags: google-search

I was trying to disprove some fictional tale being claimed as a real thing. It would help me if I could order Google search results so that **first result is the one Google found first in time**.

- **Q:** How can I order Google search results by the time Google added them to database (by the time they appeared on the internet as Google sees it)?

Comment: You can't change the sort order Google offers you. At best, you can filter by time.

Comment: @AlE. It's actually very hard to prove that something is impossible. I have of course tried and searched before posting this question. But I asked it because not finding a way to do it doesn't convince me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only Google News has the option to sort search results by date. This option is one of the "search tools". For other kind of search results, you could use the date that the web page was cached but this date show the most recent, not the first one.

For sorting Google News search results, from [Filter your search results - Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en)

> **Add or remove filters**
>   Computer
>   1. Do a search on Google.
>   2. Choose the type of result you want to see, like Images or **News**, by selecting a type under the search box. Click **More** to see extra choices.
>   3. Below the search box, click **Search tools** to see more filters you can apply to your search. The Search tools you see will be different based on your search and the filters you've already used, so you won't see all the options every time.
>   4. To remove any filters you've added through Search tools, click **Clear**.